# what is time reference of a verb

Tags: indirect-speech, sequence-of-tenses

In indirect speech if the time reference has not changed then the tenses are not back shifted.

Randolph Quirk, in *A Comprehensive Grammar of The English Language* states

> Backshift is optional when the time reference of the original utterance is valid at the time of the reported utterance.

What does it mean?
What is a ***time reference*** ?

Answer (score 1):

The time reference is the time to which the indirectly quoted speaker was referring when he said whatever he said.

Comment: @iamRR Brian wasn't responding to the broader question of when to backshift or not. He was helping you answer *this* question: interpreting the meaning of "time reference" in this specific context. In other words, he's helping you understand what Prof. Quirk is saying, not whether there are additional points to be made about backshifting.

Comment: I rather wanted to ask as to what Prof. Quirk meant to say ?

Comment: @iamRR Prof. Quirk said that backshifting is optional but not obligatory when, in the interim between the original utterance and the reporting of that utterance, the facts have **not** changed in such a way as to invalidate the phrasing (wrt tense) of the utterance as it was originally uttered. Whew!

Comment: Let's say today Kim tells me : " I hate doing Maths exercises." A week later I report her words as : Kim said that she hates doing Maths exercises. Here I used 'is' because, at the time of reporting, I know that Kim still hates doing Maths exercises . But at the same time I'm reporting something which was said a week ago, so here has time reference changed or not ?

Comment: Does Quirk want to say if the the original statement is still true at the time of reporting then back shifting is optional even if the reported speech is made a few days later or does he want to say that back shifting is optional only if the reported speech is made soon after the orinial statement was made ?

Comment: Somebody please reply.